# Italic correction fails when putting \textit into a custom command

Tags: spacing, italic, italic-correction

I am currently writing my PhD thesis (genetics) and I encountered the following problem:
The text contains a lot of gene names (italic) with mutations indicated as superscripts. So, rather than typing the whole command each time, I defined custom commands to make things easier. But the automatic italic correction does not work if it is wrapped up in an custom command (MWE below). Putting "\ " inside the command helps but messes things up, when making an enumeration.

Is there a workaround for this?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\test}{\textit{gene\textsuperscript{mutation}}}

\begin{document}
Example where spacing problems with \test show up.

Putting \textit{gene\textsuperscript{mutation}} directly into the text works perfect.
\end{document}
```